# Change default WooCommerce order status to processing for cheque and bacs payments

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, payment-method

In WooCommerce, I need all my orders to go immediately to **"processing" status** to have the order-processing email sent directly when the order is processed.

By default, this behavior exist for Paypal and COD orders, **but not for BACS and Cheque** where the default status is `on-hold`.

I tried several snippets like this one:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_process_order' );

function custom_woocommerce_auto_process_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
       return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'processing' );
}
```

But this doesn't work, the order still shows up in "on-hold" status and the processing email notification is not sent. Now I just found a this snippet:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_bacs_process_payment_order_status', function( $status = 'on_hold', $order = null ) {
    return 'processing';
}, 10, 2 );
```

And it works, but only for "BACS". How can I adapt it to also work for "Cheque" orders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The filter hook `woocommerce_cheque_process_payment_order_status` is not yet implemented in Woocommerce 3.5.7 … if you look to the file located in your woocommerce plugin under: 
>  `includes` > `gateways` > `cheque` > `class-wc-gateway-cheque.php`, the hook is missing  *(line **`122`**)*:
>
> ```
> $order->update_status( 'on-hold', _x( 'Awaiting check payment', 'Check payment method', 'woocommerce' ) );
> ```
>
> But on Github WC version 3.5.7 for [`class-wc-gateway-cheque.php` file](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/gateways/cheque/class-wc-gateway-cheque.php#L122), the hook exist *(line **`122`**)*:
>
> ```
> $order->update_status( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cheque_process_payment_order_status', 'on-hold', $order ), _x( 'Awaiting check payment', 'Check payment method', 'woocommerce' ) );
> ```

The hook will is planed to be available next WooCommerce 3.6 release, [see the file change on Woocommerce Github](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/commit/e283eff149e89cf878f98795856b248998d339e3). It's tagged `3.6.0-rc.2` and `3.6.0-beta.1`

So it will be possible to change the default order status to "processing" for "bacs" and "cheque" payment methods, using the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_bacs_process_payment_order_status','filter_process_payment_order_status_callback', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cheque_process_payment_order_status','filter_process_payment_order_status_callback', 10, 2 );
function filter_process_payment_order_status_callback( $status, $order ) {
    return 'processing';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Comment: I tried this on a fresh installment but it does not work for cheque payments. Only for bacs...

Comment: @fredrik I have updated my answer code… The hook exists on Github Woocommerce 3.5.7 …  but on all installed versions 3.5.7 the hook is missing.

Comment: @fredrik As this will be on next release, you could edit and make the change on the related core file…

Comment: You are correct Loic. I did not ever think of that! Hopefully the new version will be released soon!

Comment: This worked perfectly and was just what I needed - big thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Right now you are adding a filter for the `BACS` hook. There is a similar hook for `Cheque` payment method.

Simply add the following code:

```
add_filter( 
  'woocommerce_cheque_process_payment_order_status',
  function( $status = 'on_hold', $order = null ) {
    return 'processing';
  }, 10, 2
);
```

It does the exact same, but just for the `Cheque` orders.

Comment: I tried that, but it does not work for cheque orders! I don't know why, I had found this filter as well but it does not work...

Comment: @fredrik Try to disable all plugins except woocommerce and then use the 2019 theme. Or try to decrease or increase the priority which is `10` in my example. Try to set it to `1` and to `99`