# WooCommerce: Order status based on Payment methods

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, payment-method

On Woocommerce we have the option for BACS payments. Some orders are coming through as "Paid" and some aren't. I can't understand why as they are using the exact same payment method. The two images below will show you this:

Paid:
[image]
Not Paid:
[image]

We are using a function to automatically change these payments from "On Hold" to "Processing", in case this may have something to do with the issue. The code is below:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bacs_order_payment_processing_order_status', 10, 1 );

function bacs_order_payment_processing_order_status( $order_id ) {
if ( ! $order_id ) {
    return;
}

// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

if ( ( get_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method', true) == 'bacs' || 'cod'  ) && ('on-hold' == $order->status || 'pending' == $order->status) ) {
    $order->update_status('processing');
}

else {
    return;
}
}

// change COD payment method order status from processing to on-hold
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou_cod', 'action_woocommerce_thankyou_cod', 10, 1);
function action_woocommerce_thankyou_cod($order_id)
{
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $order->update_status('processing');
}
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is very outdated, confused with mistakes…

Instead, **to change order status for payments** like:

1. Cash on delivery `cod` use *(default status is "processing")*:

- [Change COD default order status to "On Hold" instead of "Processing" in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280800/change-cod-default-order-status-to-on-hold-instead-of-processing-in-woocomme/53291919#53291919)

2. Cash on Cheque `cheque` use *(default status is "on-hold"):

- [Change default WooCommerce order status to processing for cheque and bacs payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55656067/change-default-woocommerce-order-status-to-processing-for-cheque-and-bacs-paymen/55656788#55656788)

3. bank wire `bacs` use *(default status is "on-hold"):

- [WooCommerce change order status BACS processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597663/woocommerce-change-order-status-bacs-processing/36608333#36608333)
- [Change default WooCommerce order status to processing for cheque and bacs payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55656067/change-default-woocommerce-order-status-to-processing-for-cheque-and-bacs-paymen/55656788#55656788)

4. For other payment gateways use (default order status is related to each payment gateway and if there are shippable items or not):

- [WooCommerce: Auto complete paid orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders/35689563#35689563)
- [Auto process paid orders instead of auto complete in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998386/auto-process-paid-orders-instead-of-auto-complete-in-woocommerce/63998682#63998682)