# How to autocomplete a virtual product if it is purchased with physical products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have an e-commerce WordPress website. Where I am using woocommerce. I am also using an autocomplete plugin to autocomplete my virtual products but now the issue is that. My client is selling subscriptions with a physical product. What should I do? i want the status of virtual product to complete but want the status of physical product to processing.

Please guide how to achieve this.

I tried with the autocomplete plugin but if both are purchased then the status is processing.

Comment: The order status is defined by the payment method. There are many examples how to change default status of a payment method to whatever you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66658628/woocommerce-order-status-based-on-payment-methods